# How to add breadcrumb to Product in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, json-ld

The product page of my website has a breadcrumb.

The `Product` type has not `breadcrumb`.

I do this:

```json
"@type": "Webpage",
"breadcrumb": {...
"mainEntity":
     { 
        "@type": "Product",
        ...
```

Am I right? (I used `"@type": "Webpage"` only for breadcrumb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your idea is correct.

As breadcrumbs are part of web pages, not of products, the [`breadcrumb` property](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) is only defined for [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage).

Note that you must use `WebPage` instead of `Webpage`. Schema.org terms are case-sensitive.

For a page with a single product, you can consider using (the more specific) [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) instead of `WebPage`.

Comment: I'm still unsure of the final json ld for a product page with breadcrumbs and struggling to find examples.

Comment: @Abram: Here is [a full JSON-LD example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/99999/17633) with `WebPage` and `BreadcrumbList`. For the `Product`, you would simply add it as value to the `WebPage`’s `mainEntity` property.

Comment: Apparently you cannot add BreadcrumbList to Product, so I had to use @graph to accomplish this.

Comment: @Abram: Yes, you can’t add it to `Product`, but (what this question here is about) you can add it to `WebPage`. So the best solution is to use `WebPage`, and add the `BreadcrumbList` and the `Product` to it.

Comment: @unor How to connect breadcrumb to Webpage, if I choose not to declare breadcrumb within Webpage (ie when breadcrumb in a separate json-ld script)? I was thinking that we can use isPartOf, but looking up schema.org for breadcrumb doesn't show this property.

Comment: @Ethan: Please ask this as a question (showing the JSON-LD you have). The comment section isn’t a suitable place for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to schema.org [documentation](https://schema.org/breadcrumb) for breadcrumb you can use [BreadcrumbList](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList). So something like this:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "breadcrumb": {
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "@id": "https://example.com/dresses",
                "name": "Dresses"
            }
        }, {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
                "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real",
                "name": "Real Dresses"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```